# How to identify revision at which branch was created using SVN copy on Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I created a branch using `svn copy` on Linux, but I'd like to do some merging on Windows using Tortoise SVN. When I opened it up, I saw it has some context sensitive options (right click) to create branches. Since I didn't do that, it doesn't know which revision I created the branch from, it looks like. Can I specify the revision at which the branch was created manually in Tortoise SVN somehow? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`svn copy` records where you've copied from, as well as the revision. It doesn't matter if you use `svn copy` on the command line, copy from TortoiseSVN's Repository Browser or using the branch/tag entry of the context menu.

In TortoiseSVN you can see the copy operation in the log window. The file(s) shown has a "copied from URL" column (you might need to enable that column first though).

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to be able to see it when I do a TortoiseSVN merge. I don't see it indicated there. I am able to see it when I do a TortoiseSVN > Check log (and that was not new to me). But I'd like to see it indicated when doing the Merge, so that I know which all revisions on trunk I can focus on. I believe if you create the branch from TortoiseSVN, it does that for you, whereas if you create it independently using svn copy, it doesn't. That's my understanding. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't. I use TortoiseSVN at work and finding revisions to merge from trunk to a branch is always a pain even though I always use "branch/tag" instead of a command-line svn copy. There are actually two "show log" buttons on the TortoiseSVN merge dialog. I use show log on the merge destination to find the branch point, then I use show log on the merge source to select the revisions after that point.

Comment: @Ben - "finding revisions to merge from trunk to a branch is always a pain" only in your brain. **Just not define range** if you perform sync-merge between nodes (SVN is rather smart to detect correct range in most cases)

Comment: Then the TSVN UI is misleading. When you "show log" when merging from branch to trunk, all previously merged revisions are shown grayed out, making it obvious that SVN won't merge those (or you shouldn't merge them manually). When you merge from trunk to branch, nothing is grayed out unless you've manually merged that revision.